# Can't access private variable in a Swift class that extends an Objective - C class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cordova, webview

Our app is a hybrid app uses Cordova. As such a lot of logic is done in the webview.

I've hit a scenario where I need to access the webview object.

Problem is I can't get my hands on it!

Here is the base class `CDVPlugin.h`:

```
@interface UIView (org_apache_cordova_UIView_Extension)

@end

// Stuff

@interface CDVPlugin : NSObject {}

@property (nonatomic, readonly, weak) UIView* webView; // This is what I want
```

Diving into the `CDVPlugin.m` file it looks like this:

```
@interface CDVPlugin ()

// Other codes

- (UIView*)webView
{
    if (self.webViewEngine != nil) {
        return self.webViewEngine.engineWebView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

And my `Bridge.swift` file that extends CDVPlugin looks like this:

```
@objc(Bridge) class Bridge:CDVPlugin
{
   func getWebView() -> UIWebView
   {
     self.webView // Does not exist
   }
}
```

I'm even more confused because other sub-classes of this are able to access this webView variable. For example this plugin class:

```
#import "CDVPlugin.h"

@interface CDVGestureHandler : CDVPlugin

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILongPressGestureRecognizer* lpgr;

@end
```

Is able to access the private method just fine?

```
#import "CDVGestureHandler.h"

@implementation CDVGestureHandler

- (void)pluginInitialize
{
   NSArray *views = self.webView.subviews;
}
```

I'm not sure why some other Objc classes are able to access a private method from its parent or why I can't access it from my Swift class that extends it.

If you can advise how I can access this `webView` object I am all ears!

Test showing how self can't access it but an instance can.
[image]

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem using a simplified example involving a property (readonly) with a type of a category on NSString, but I was able to access the property from a derived Swift class.  A few questions/ideas:
- Can you instantiate `CDVPlugin` in your Swift code and access the property?
- Try creating a property of type `NSString*` that returns, say, @"MY PROPERTY" and see if it is accessible from Swift.
- How do you know that `self.webView` does not exist?  Is it not listed in the Xcode hints?
- Is the property implementation located in the correct @implementation section?

Comment: Interestingly if I instantiate it, I have access. But I can't access it from a self instance

Answer (score 0):

Slight derp moment.

My class was using a global function so it couldnt access a member variable. The error message was throwing me off base.

> "Instance member cannot be used on type Bridge".

I see now that it means it was an instance access in a class func. I wonder if the loremaster for Dark Souls 3 wrote the compiler errors.